# Nock Throws 'AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Mocks not yet satisfied'

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, nock

I am trying to mock the URI `http://102.10.10.337:9391/v2.0/networks` using `nock` with the following code:

```
const allowUnmocked = { allowUnmocked: true };

const networkScope = nock('http://102.10.10.337:9391/v2.0/', allowUnmocked)
.persist();

console.log(networkScope);

let checknock = networkScope.post('/networks')
    .reply(200, (uri, networkPayload) => {
        console.log('dockedd');
        return {
            network: {
                'provider:physical_network': null,           
                mtu: 1450
            }
        };
    });

try {
    checknock.done();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`boom! -> ${e}`); // pass exception object to error handler
}
```

Upon running it, I receive the following error:

`AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Mocks not yet satisfied`

Answer (score 0):

Probably something to do with duplicate usage of `/`.

```
const networkScope = nock('http://102.10.10.337:9391/v2.0', allowUnmocked)
// ...
const checknock = networkScope.post('/networks')
```

Comment: const networkScope = nock('http://102.10.10.337:9391/v2.0', allowUnmocked);
i changed it but still it throws same error :(

Comment: I was able to nock the URL

Comment: what did you change? can you please post an answer?

Comment: if anyone else hits this, you can use .log(console.log) on the nock() instance to see what's going on and what is or is not being hit. This solved my problem.

Comment: The log function is no more available on newer versions of nock e.g. v13.0.0 but you can set the DEBUG environment variable to nock.* as described here https://github.com/nock/nock#debugging to log each step of the matching process.